# Woes using Word Interop - Inserting an image on a template

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

I have tried a number of different solutions to trying to insert an image into a document template.  I have had a couple successes but not with desired effects.  Basically, I am just trying to insert an image at the top of a document above all other content.  The image should at best move the rest of the content down the page, and not on top of anything.

```
    With objDoc
        Dim filePath As String = Path.Combine(appPath, fileName)
        If Not filePath = "" Then
            Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile(filePath)
            Dim imgX As Integer = img.Width
            Dim imgY As Integer = img.Height

            'insert picture here
        End If
    End With
```

Replacing the comment above with the following, I have had success...sort of.  The following will insert the image into the header.  But the image will get scaled in very odd ways, regardless of defining the image parameters.

```
            .PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
            .Sections(1).Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes.AddPicture(
               FileName:=filePath,
               LinkToFile:=False,
               SaveWithDocument:=True,
               Left:=0,
               Top:=0,
               Width:=imgX,
               Height:=imgY
        ).ConvertToInlineShape()
```

The following will insert the image, underneath the header and on top of text.  Trying to convert it to an inlineshape throws an exception.  Giving the canvass a `0,0` start in this case ignores the template margins and puts the image to the left edge of the sheet.  Even if I were to shift it to the right and get the text to shift down, it's still not desirable as there is too much white space at the top.

```
        Dim objCanvas As Word.Shape = objWordApp.ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddCanvas(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=imgX, Height:=imgY)
        objCanvas.CanvasItems.AddPicture(FileName:=filePath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
```

The rest of the following were attempts at what I found sifting through msdn and various other outlets.  None of these show any image at all.

```
               '.InlineShapes.AddPicture(filePath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)

                'Dim objRng As Word.Range = .Range()
                'objRng.InlineShapes.AddPicture(filePath)

                'Dim objInlineShape As Word.InlineShape = objWordApp.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(
                '    FileName:=filePath,
                '    LinkToFile:=False,
                '    SaveWithDocument:=True
                ')
                'objInlineShape.LockAspectRatio = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue
                'objInlineShape.Width = imgX
                'objInlineShape.Height = imgY

                '.Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(filePath)

                'Dim objRng As Word.Range = .Sections(1).Range()
                'objRng.InlineShapes.AddPicture(filePath)
                '
                'Dim objInlineShape As Word.InlineShape = .InlineShapes.AddPicture(filePath)
                'Dim objShape As Word.Shape = objInlineShape.ConvertToShape()

                'objDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\startofdoc").Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(filePath)
```

The document itself is just four tables with some formatting.  What the heck am I doing wrong?

Comment: `objDoc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes.AddPicture(filePath, False, True, Width:=imgX, Height:=imgY)` works for me

Answer (score 0):

The following code is from one of my VB.Net add-ins.

```
                rng = rng.Rows(1).Cells(1).Range
                rng.Delete()
                rng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
                rng.InlineShapes.AddPicture(.SelectedItems(i))
```

It is adding an image into a table cell. The "SelectItems(i)" reference is to the image file that the user has selected from a msoFileDialogFilePicker function, and you can change that to any known file path for your image. I am posting it to show you an example of actual code.

Getting your image to the top of the document is as simple as setting the insert range to that location. This following code will do it.

```
Dim rng as Word.Range
rng = ActiveDocument.Content
rng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart)
rng.InlineShapes.AddPicture(Your Path)
```